# use of rdf data in ontology

Tags: import, rdf, ontology

My work deals with rdf data published in web or rdf data that I have already generated.

I want to combine these rdf data in my ontology work file.

Simply, I want to create an ontology file, but this ontology file may have only definitions, class definitons etc.. The class entities or instances will be populated from rdf files.

As far as i understand, we need to define each rdf resource/class/instance definitions in ontology file too. But this is a heavy double work I guess. I have already defined resources in rdf files but I want to define these data in ontology too only by using referring to rdf file content.

Is it possible ? and is there any samples for this ?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you're talking of owl ontologies, you can create an owl ontology for your definitions and an owl ontology with owl:imports directives to include definitions and rdf data.

Comment: As written, this is probably too broad. But, as Ignazio says, you just create the instance data in another ontology file that **imports** the definitions ontology.